# method to make this for-loop faster in C++ possibly with NVidia?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, cuda

I want to make a C++ function faster. I am asking you about potential ways to do it.

I can use up to 32 OMP threads.

I can use an NVidia GPU.

A MWE for the function is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

typedef std::numeric_limits<double> dbl;
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <omp.h>

const std::complex<double> I(0.0, 1.0); // imaginary unit, I*I = -1
std::complex<double> zero_imag (0.0, 0.0);

const int N_rs = 1500;
const int l_max = 70;
const int lmax = 70;
const int N_thetas = l_max + 1;
const int N_phis = 2 * l_max + 2;
const int N_ps = 600;
const int nphi = 2 * l_max + 2;
const double sqrt_of_2_over_pi = sqrt( 2.0 / M_PI );


void rtop(std::complex<double> * Psi_outer_spec,
          std::complex<double> * Psi_outer_spec_plm,
          double * BJ,
          double * wrk,
          std::complex<double> * wrk2,
          double * ris_without_ends,
          double * r_primes_without_ends,
          double * weights_Lobatto_without_ends
         )
{


    int l, kk, kkk, m;
    long int idx, idxx, idxxx;

    // #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate (wrk2) private(l, kkk, idx, m, kk, idxx, idxxx) schedule(static)
    // #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for firstprivate(wrk2) private(l, kkk, idx, m, kk, idxx, idxxx)
    for (int i = 0; i <= (N_ps - 1); i++) { // THIS IS THE BOTTLENECK !!!
       
        std::complex<double> sum1 = std::complex<double> (0.0, 0.0); // each thread creates a sum1 on its own

        for (l = 0; l <= lmax; l++) {

            for (kkk = 0; kkk <= (N_rs-1); kkk++) {
                idx = i * (N_rs*(l_max+1)) + kkk * (l_max+1) + l;
                wrk2[kkk] = pow(-I, l) * BJ[idx] * wrk[kkk];
            }

            for (m = 0; m <= (nphi-1); m++) {

                sum1 = zero_imag;
                for (kk = 0; kk <= (N_rs-1); kk++) {
                    idxx = kk * (N_thetas*N_phis) + l * N_phis + m;
                    sum1 += Psi_outer_spec[idxx] * wrk2[kk];

                }

                idxxx = i * (N_thetas*N_phis) + l * N_phis + m;
                Psi_outer_spec_plm[idxxx] = sum1 * sqrt_of_2_over_pi;
                                       
            }
            // END for m loop
        }
        // END for l loop
    }    
    // END for i loop
}

int main() {

    double * wrk = new double [N_rs];
    std::complex<double> * wrk2 = new std::complex<double> [N_rs];

    double * ris_without_ends = new double [N_rs];
    double * r_primes_without_ends = new double [N_rs];
    double * weights_Lobatto_without_ends = new double [N_rs];

    double * BJ = new double [N_ps * N_rs * (l_max+1)];

    std::complex<double> * Psi_outer_spec = new std::complex<double> [N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis];
    std::complex<double> * Psi_outer_spec_plm = new std::complex<double> [N_ps * N_thetas * N_phis];

    rtop(Psi_outer_spec, Psi_outer_spec_plm, BJ, wrk, wrk2, ris_without_ends, r_primes_without_ends, weights_Lobatto_without_ends);
   
    return 0;
}
```

The associated CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")

project(trial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -pedantic -Wall")

find_package(OpenMP)

add_executable(trial trial.cpp)

if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
target_link_libraries(trial PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
endif()

set_property(TARGET trial PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Compile as: `$ cmake ..`  then `$ cmake --build . --config Release`.

My output is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /apps20/sw/eb/software/GCCcore/11.3.0/bin/gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /apps20/sw/eb/software/GCCcore/11.3.0/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /work4/clf/ouatu/trial_for_SO/build
```

Then for the build:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/trial.dir/trial.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable trial
[100%] Built target trial
```

What I have tried:

- With OpenMP parallel for, I do get speedup.
- I fail with OpenMP GPU-offloading (it seems my compiler flags do not
  make the offloading possible). (these flags are hidden from the shown `CMakeLists.txt` for this MWE)
- I am open to any other suggestions.

For example, would `rtop` benefit from being a CUDA kernel? Is it hard to make it that way?

Thank you!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253890/discussion-on-question-by-velenos14-method-to-make-this-for-loop-faster-in-c-p); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest an OpenMP version with some optimizations and tweaks. A quick review of some changes and what to look out for:

The whole business with `wrk2[kkk] = pow(-I, l) * ...`  is doubly redundant. For one, `pow(-I, l)` is an elegant but expensive way of expressing just 4 different values. Second, it's only used as a factor in a dot product. You can fold the whole thing into the final multiplication `sum1 * sqrt_of_2_over_pi`. That also allows `wrk2` to be real-valued, which also turns the innermost loop from a complex-complex dot product to a complex-real dot product.

The multi-dimensional index calculations like `idx = i * (N_rs*(l_max+1)) + kkk * (l_max+1) + l` should be done following the [Horner method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to avoid redundant multiplications. More of a nitpick but also clearner. For example here `idx = (i * N_rs + kkk) * (l_max+1) + l`. While we're at it, be careful with your index variables. They are all int. Especially the 3-dimensional arrays can quickly grow to multiple GiB in size at which point you will experience integer overflows. Switch to `std::ptrdiff_t` if you fear that this may become a problem.

The order of iterations over `BJ` and `Psi_outer_spec_plm` aren't ideal. If possible, `BJ` should swap the two inner dimensions for better locality of data, which would also allow for vectorization of the loop initializing `wrk2`. `Psi_outer_spec` is even worse because you iterate along the outer dimension in your innermost loop. However, I assume this order was picked so that it is the same as with `Psi_outer_spec_plm` and for that it is good. In any case, this higher stride prevents vectorization.

I don't see a reason why you declare counter and index variables outside the scope where they are used. Even modern C standards allow declaring them inside for loops, let alone C++. For parallelization, you want to limit the number of shared or accidentally shared variables.

Speaking of shared data, as far as I can see, the only shared memory in which threads may overlap is the `wrk2` array. That can simply be allocated per thread, which brings us to the final implementation.

```cpp
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
        auto wrk2 = std::make_unique<double[]>(N_rs);
#       pragma omp for collapse(2) nowait
        for (int i = 0; i <= (N_ps - 1); i++) {
            for (int l = 0; l <= lmax; l++) {
                for (int kkk = 0; kkk <= (N_rs-1); kkk++) {
                    int idx = (i * N_rs + kkk) * (lmax + 1) + l;
                    wrk2[kkk] = BJ[idx] * wrk[kkk];
                }
                constexpr std::complex<double> I(0., 1.);
                std::complex<double> factor(-sqrt_of_2_over_pi);
                if(l & 1)
                    factor *= I;
                if(l & 2)
                    factor = -factor;
                for (int m = 0; m <= (N_phis-1); m++) {
                    std::complex<double> sum1;
                    for (int kk = 0; kk <= (N_rs-1); kk++) {
                        int idx = (kk * N_thetas + l) * N_phis + m;
                        sum1 += Psi_outer_spec[idx] * wrk2[kk];
                    }
                    int idx = (i * N_thetas + l) * N_phis + m;
                    Psi_outer_spec_plm[idx] = sum1 * factor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note how the usual `pragma omp parallel for` is split into an `omp parallel` and a separate `omp for` to allow for allocating the temporary memory. The `collapse(2)` means that both outer loops are parallelized.

Other things to consider:

- The inner dot product may be computed faster by an accelerated BLAS library or something similar. I think [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) should work well here but one might need to coerce it a bit into working with this memory layout
- It looks somewhat like we could change the `m` loop into a matrix-vector product, which might solve some of our vectorization / memory access issues via a BLAS library
- Since you asked about compile options, `-march=native` or whatever baseline architecture you want should be worthwhile here. `-mavx2 -mfma` may be a good compromise to handle all relatively recent CPUs without specializing the binary too much

### Edit: Matrix-vector product

Coming back to the idea to offload the loop over `m` into a matrix vector product, we have to reinterpret the slice of `Psi_outer_spec` that we use as a matrix. I choose a column-major matrix since I want to use Eigen3 for this step.

- The number of rows are `N_phi` (loop counter `m`)
- The number of columns are `N_rs` (loop counter `kk`)
- From one column to the next we have a stride / a.k.a. leading dimension of `N_phi * N_theta`
- The offset of the top left corner is `l * N_phis`

Assuming this is correct, we can map our arrays into Eigen vectors and matrices and let it handle the transposed accesses. This turns everything below the `wrk2` initialization into this code

```cpp
using MatrixMap = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXcd,
        Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::OuterStride<>>;
MatrixMap Psi_slice(
        Psi_outer_spec + l * N_phis /*top left corner*/,
        N_phis /*rows*/, N_rs /*cols*/,
        Eigen::OuterStride<>(N_phis * N_thetas));
const auto wrk2_mapped = Eigen::VectorXd::Map(wrk2.get(), N_rs);
auto Psi_plm_mapped = Eigen::VectorXcd::Map(
        Psi_outer_spec_plm + (i * N_thetas + l) * N_phis, N_phis);
Psi_plm_mapped.noalias() = Psi_slice * wrk2_mapped * factor;
```

And now this step obviously raises the question of whether we can turn the whole thing into a matrix-matrix product with some pre- or post-processing, which might take care of the entire parallelization and potential offloading to GPUs. **And this is why I asked for a mathematical description instead of doing this wild goose chase through the code**

### Edit 2: Matrix-matrix product

It is indeed possible to rewrite it as a matrix-matrix product. The trick is the observation that `Psi_outer_spec` is independent from `i`. Therefore if we switch the two outer loops, we can compute all values for one `l` over all `i` in one operation.

While doing so, I switch back to `wrk2` being complex and including the factor. This technically requires more compute time and memory but with a matrix-matrix product, you may want to dispatch to a BLAS backend, either directly for example via [OpenBLAS](https://www.openblas.net/), via [Eigen's backends](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html) or even GPU acceleration such as [CuBLAS](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-t-gemm). And for that you need a complex-complex multiplication.

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXcd wrk2mat(N_rs, N_ps);
for (int l = 0; l <= lmax; l++) {
    std::complex<double> factor(-sqrt_of_2_over_pi);
    if(l & 1)
        factor *= I;
    if(l & 2)
        factor = -factor;
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i <= N_ps - 1; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= N_rs - 1; ++k) {
            int idx = (i * N_rs + k) * (lmax + 1) + l;
            wrk2mat(k, i) = BJ[idx] * wrk[k] * factor;
        }
    }
    using ConstMatrixMap = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXcd,
            Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::OuterStride<>>;
    ConstMatrixMap Psi_slice(
            Psi_outer_spec + l * N_phis /*top left corner*/,
            N_phis /*rows*/, N_rs /*cols*/,
            Eigen::OuterStride<>(N_phis * N_thetas));
    using MatrixMap = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcd,
            Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::OuterStride<>>;
    MatrixMap Psi_plm_mapped(
            Psi_outer_spec_plm + l * N_phis,
            N_phis, N_ps,
            Eigen::OuterStride<>((lmax + 1) * N_phis));
    Psi_plm_mapped.noalias() = Psi_slice * wrk2mat;
}
```

The matrix-matrix product should be internally parallelized as long as the matrices are large enough. If this is not always the case, you can wrap the whole thing into an runtime-optional parallel block. Roughly like this:

```cpp
bool small_matrices = ...;
#pragma omp parallel if(small_matrices)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXcd wrk2mat(N_rs, N_ps);
#   pragma omp for nowait
    for (int l = 0; l <= lmax; l++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since OpenMP normally deactivates nested parallelization, this will automatically deactivate all the inner `parallel` sections and run them sequentially.

Comment: `pow(-I, l)` is rotating clockwise around the unit circle, in 4 steps of 90 degrees (-i, -1, +i, 1). Can't do that in a single bit op. Still, a `phase *= -I;`  with a `constexpr I` is compile-time trivial.

Comment: @Homer512, wow. This is impressive. Thank you very much for analyzing this in so much detail. I will study what you wrote.

Comment: @Homer512, if you invested so much effort into this, would you please spare a few moments and convert from the Eigen Matrix command after ``Psi_plm_mapped.noalias() = Psi_slice * wrk2mat;`` back to normal C arrays? I further postprocess ``Psi_outer_spec_plm`` after this function returns, with other commands which assume ``Psi_outer_spec_plm`` to be a long 1D C array of ``(N_ps * N_thetas * N_phis)`` elements.

Comment: @velenos14 It's an [`Eigen::Map`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) which means it's not a new array, it works directly on the pointer that I passed into it. So you can still access the result through your raw pointers

Comment: @Homer512, a closing curly brace ``}`` is missing from your EDIT 2 , first code block, correct ? I suspect it shall be in place right at the end of the code block ? Thanks

Comment: @Homer512, I appreciate all your help on this. I have gone through what you did, nice. For the input parameters I need ( larger than in this question ), one iteration of the function takes roughly 500-600 milliseconds. Do you know an alternative to make your work use cuBLAS for the Matr-Matr multiplication? Do you know how to port the eigen matrices to LibTorch (which works in my code and the torch.matmul command dispatches to cuBLAS) ? Or maybe you suggest another alternative? I know that for matrix sizes of (1500, 1500) or around these values, cuBLAS can be beneficial.

Comment: @MSalters, what do you mean with ``constexpr I`` ? in my code, ``I`` is: ``const std::complex<double> I(0.0, 1.0); // imaginary unit, I*I = -1``. An if-statement to check for the result of ``l % 4`` is what I need, right? With 4 branches inside the if-statement.

Comment: @Homer512, basically my question is targeting this last part of the following workflow (the continuation marks): I create 2 ``LibTorch`` tensors from the 2 ``eigen`` MatrixMaps, perform the MM-multiplication, store the result in another ``LibTorch`` tensor, ... <-- what to do (/how) with this resulting LibTorch tensor to update ``Psi_outer_spec_plm`` as your ``eigen`` operation's result does via ``Psi_plm_mapped`` ?

Comment: @velenos14 the main concern with going for GPU computing is that your stuff is in double precision. At least consumer-grade GPUs don't have a lot of performance in that precision, see for example [in this benchmark](https://www.thefpsreview.com/2020/09/21/geforce-rtx-3080-fe-gpgpu-compute-workstation-performance/3/) 500 GFlops in double compared to 30000 GFlops in float. You should first check whether single precision is acceptable to you

Comment: @Homer512, thank you. I can immediately respond that single precision is not particularly good for my case, I do Quantum-Chemistry and we sometimes look at changes in the 18-th decimal (or so) of quantities of interest. The GPU on my cluster is A100, idk if that helps or not

Comment: The A100 does have strong double performance. I'm not familiar with Libtorch but if that's part of your code-base, why didn't you start with that? Especially now that it is clear that the entire thing is just a set of matrix multiplications, there is no reason not to use it. The setup of `wrk2` is also just a multiplication between tensors with some broadcasting; basically the tensor-equivalent of matrix multiplication with a diagonal matrix

Comment: @Homer512, thanks. I wrote this function using raw C-pointers and for-loops because I didn't see the tricks you used to convert everything into MM multiplications. LibTorch has moderately slow CPU-tensor random-access indexing, and I couldn't figure it out how to random-access index CUDA tensors. So I will keep everything you did, the only change would be the MM at end to be in Torch. ATM, the speedup increase with your tricks and using MKL + Eigen on 32 OMP cores is magnificent. I might get my results using this only, but would be nice to make it use the GPU for the MM. I will give it a try.

Comment: @velenos14 Can you update the question with your benchmark result (original time cost vs new time cost) for reference ? As well as the full code to run the new version if possible so we can easily compare them. Thanks!

Comment: @HuyLe, the original code wouldn't run in a feasible time, the updated Eigen code runs in seconds. When I will find some spare time, I will update the question. The original code can be tested by anyone with a C++ compiler, but it's just too slow ...

Comment: I ran both versions and found that sometimes they produce slightly incorrect result: the original code give `(X,Y)` but the Eigen code gives `(-X,-Y)`. Have you checked that both versions give the same output ? I'm also testing another solution using GPU CuBlas

Answer (score 3):

**10x faster solution using GPU and CuBLAS. Also fix wrong result bug from current accepted answer**

**Test computer specs:**

- Ryzen 2950X, quad channel RAM 2133MHz
- 2080ti (terrible at FP64)
- PCIE 3.0 x16 lanes
- Ubuntu 20.04, CUDA 12.1, Eigen 3.3.9
- IDK what backend Eigen is using because it's not my PC, I think it's MKL

**The time cost for each implementation using this PC:**

- Original code: ~75s
- Eigen code OMP_NUM_THREADS=1: 8s
- Eigen code OMP_NUM_THREADS=16: 1.1s
- **CUDA + CuBLAS: 0.26s**.

I measure each segment by using `MyTimer` and `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after each CUDA call (not shown in the code below). The total run time when not measuring is slightly lower, because some transfer/compute is being overlapped (I think).

- `BJ, d_wrk, Psi_outer_spec` Host to Device transfer: ~50ms
- `compute_wrk2mat`: ~15ms
- `cublasZgemmStridedBatched`: ~180ms
- `Psi_outer_spec_plm` Device to Host transfer: ~10ms

**Predicting 2080ti vs A100 performance:**

- FP32: 13.45 TFLOP vs 19.75 TFLOP
- **FP64: 0.42 TFLOP vs 9.75 TFLOP**
- Memory bandwidth: 616 GB/s vs 1555 GB/s
- PCIE 4.0 is 2x faster than 3.0

So I predict the `A100` will run this in `(50ms + 10ms) * 0.5 (pcie_transfer)` + `15ms * 616 / 1555 (memory_bound_kernel)` + `180ms / 10 (fp64_compute_bound_kernel` ~~**50ms** . If anyone has free time, please run a benchmark because I'm also curious.

---

Finally, the code. First, the accepted answer (super interesting and well analyzed, btw) has a small mistake that causes it to output different results compared to your original code in the question.

```
    std::complex<double> factor(-sqrt_of_2_over_pi);
    if(l & 1)
        factor *= I;
    if(l & 2)
        factor = -factor;
```

it should be

```
    std::complex<double> factor(sqrt_of_2_over_pi);
    if(l & 1)
        factor *= -I;
    if(l & 2)
        factor = -factor;
```

**The code below is a full runnable program that benchmark + check correctness of all 3 implementations in this post**. The GPU version uses a class `RtopCalculator` object instead of a function, so that it can reuse resources (device arrays) instead of allocate/free each time the function is called. The class is RAII, and will safely free resources when destructed.

I dont use pinned memory because the expected use case is passing array from Numpy (OP says so in comment). So using normal memory is a better practical benchmark.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <omp.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>

//------------
// Utility stuffs to test
// Helper function to check cuBLAS status
#define CUBLAS_CHECK(err)                                                                          \
    do {                                                                                           \
        cublasStatus_t err_ = (err);                                                               \
        if (err_ != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {                                                       \
            printf("cublas error %d at %s:%d\n", err_, __FILE__, __LINE__);                        \
            throw std::runtime_error("cublas error");                                              \
        }                                                                                          \
    } while (0)

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool printing = false)
{   
  if (code != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::string mess = std::string("GPUassert: ") + std::string(cudaGetErrorString(code)) 
                  + " " + std::string(file) + " " + std::to_string(line);
    if (printing) std::cout << mess << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error(mess.c_str());
  }

  auto lastError = cudaGetLastError();
  if (lastError != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::string mess = std::string("GPUassert: ") + std::string(cudaGetErrorString(lastError)) 
                  + " " + std::string(file) + " " + std::to_string(line);
    std::cout << "UNDETECTED_ERROR " << mess << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error(mess.c_str());
  }
}

// CUDA API error checking
#define CUDA_CHECK(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__, true); }
#define CUDA_CHECK_NOLOG(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

double eps_ = 1e-6;

template <typename num_t>
num_t rcmp(num_t a, num_t b, num_t eps = eps_) {
    if (std::isnan(a) && std::isnan(b)) return 0;
    if (std::isnan(a + b)) return NAN;
    num_t t = (a - b) / (std::max(std::abs(a), std::abs(b)) + 1e-18);
    return t < -eps ? -1 : +eps < t;
}

class MyTimer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;

public:
    void startCounter() {
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    int64_t getCounterNs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    int64_t getCounterMs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    double getCounterMsPrecise() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count()
                / 1000000.0;
    }
};


//----------------
//----------------
//----------------

std::mt19937 rander(42);
double myrand() {
    return double(rander() % 10000) / (rander() % 10000 + 1);
}

const std::complex<double> I(0.0, 1.0); // imaginary unit, I*I = -1
std::complex<double> zero_imag (0.0, 0.0);
const double sqrt_of_2_over_pi = sqrt( 2.0 / M_PI   );

void GenData(
    int64_t N_rs, int64_t l_max, int64_t N_ps,
    std::complex<double>* Psi_outer_spec, double* BJ, double* wrk
)
{
    int64_t N_thetas = l_max + 1;
    int64_t N_phis = 2 * l_max + 2;

    for (int64_t i = 0; i < N_rs; i++) wrk[i] = myrand();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < N_ps * N_rs * N_thetas; i++) BJ[i] = myrand();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis; i++) {
        Psi_outer_spec[i].real(myrand());
        Psi_outer_spec[i].imag(myrand());
    }
}

void rtop(
    int64_t N_rs, int64_t l_max, int64_t N_ps,
    const std::complex<double>* __restrict__ Psi_outer_spec,
    std::complex<double>* __restrict__ Psi_outer_spec_plm,
    const double* __restrict__ BJ,
    const double* __restrict__ wrk,
    std::complex<double>* __restrict__ wrk2,
    double* __restrict__ ris_without_ends = nullptr,
    double* __restrict__ r_primes_without_ends = nullptr,
    double* __restrict__ weights_Lobatto_without_ends = nullptr
    )
{        
    int64_t N_thetas = l_max + 1;
    int64_t N_phis = 2 * l_max + 2;

    int64_t l, kk, kkk, m;
    int64_t idx, idxx, idxxx;

    for (int64_t i = 0; i <= (N_ps - 1); i++) { // THIS IS THE BOTTLENECK !!!
       
        std::complex<double> sum1 = std::complex<double> (0.0, 0.0); // each thread creates a sum1 on its own

        for (l = 0; l <= l_max; l++) {

            for (kkk = 0; kkk <= (N_rs-1); kkk++) {
                idx = i * (N_rs*(l_max+1)) + kkk * (l_max+1) + l;
                wrk2[kkk] = pow(-I, l) * BJ[idx] * wrk[kkk];
            }

            for (m = 0; m <= (N_phis-1); m++) {

                sum1 = zero_imag;
                for (kk = 0; kk <= (N_rs-1); kk++) {
                    idxx = kk * (N_thetas*N_phis) + l * N_phis + m;
                    sum1 += Psi_outer_spec[idxx] * wrk2[kk];
                }

                idxxx = i * (N_thetas*N_phis) + l * N_phis + m;
                Psi_outer_spec_plm[idxxx] = sum1 * sqrt_of_2_over_pi;
                                       
            }
            // END for m loop
        }
        // END for l loop
    }    
    // END for i loop
}

void rtop_eigen(
    int64_t N_rs, int64_t l_max, int64_t N_ps,
    const std::complex<double>* __restrict__ Psi_outer_spec,
    std::complex<double>* __restrict__ Psi_outer_spec_plm,
    const double* __restrict__ BJ,
    const double* __restrict__ wrk,
    std::complex<double>* __restrict__ wrk2,
    double* __restrict__ ris_without_ends = nullptr,
    double* __restrict__ r_primes_without_ends = nullptr,
    double* __restrict__ weights_Lobatto_without_ends = nullptr
)
{
    int64_t N_thetas = l_max + 1;
    int64_t N_phis = 2 * l_max + 2;

    Eigen::MatrixXcd wrk2mat(N_rs, N_ps);
    for (int64_t l = 0; l <= l_max; l++) {
        std::complex<double> factor(sqrt_of_2_over_pi);
        if(l & 1)
            factor *= -I;
        if(l & 2)
            factor = -factor;
    #   pragma omp parallel for
        for (int64_t i = 0; i <= N_ps - 1; i++) {
            for (int64_t k = 0; k <= N_rs - 1; ++k) {
                int64_t idx = (i * N_rs + k) * (l_max + 1) + l;
                wrk2mat(k, i) = BJ[idx] * wrk[k] * factor;
            }
        }
        using ConstMatrixMap = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXcd,
                Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::OuterStride<>>;
        ConstMatrixMap Psi_slice(
                Psi_outer_spec + l * N_phis /*top left corner*/,
                N_phis /*rows*/, N_rs /*cols*/,
                Eigen::OuterStride<>(N_phis * N_thetas));
        using MatrixMap = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcd,
                Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::OuterStride<>>;
        MatrixMap Psi_plm_mapped(
                Psi_outer_spec_plm + l * N_phis,
                N_phis, N_ps,
                Eigen::OuterStride<>((l_max + 1) * N_phis));
        Psi_plm_mapped.noalias() = Psi_slice * wrk2mat;
    }
}

namespace {
__global__
void compute_wrk2mat(
    int64_t N_ps, int64_t N_rs, int64_t l_max,
    const double* __restrict__ BJ,
    const double* __restrict__ wrk,
    cuDoubleComplex* __restrict__ wrk2mat
)
{
    constexpr double sqrt_of_2_over_pi = 0.79788456080286535587989;

    for (int l = 0; l <= (int)l_max; l++) {
        cuDoubleComplex* wrk2mat_offset = wrk2mat + l * N_rs * N_ps;
        
        double factor_real = sqrt_of_2_over_pi;
        double factor_imag = 0;
        if (l & 1) {
            double temp_real = factor_real;
            factor_real = factor_imag;
            factor_imag = -temp_real;
        }
        if (l & 2) {
            factor_real = -factor_real;
            factor_imag = -factor_imag;
        }

        for (int i = blockIdx.x; i < N_ps; i += gridDim.x)
            for (int k = threadIdx.x; k < N_rs; k += blockDim.x) {
                int64_t idx = (i * N_rs + k) * (l_max + 1) + l;
                wrk2mat_offset[k + i * N_rs].x = BJ[idx] * wrk[k] * factor_real;
                wrk2mat_offset[k + i * N_rs].y = BJ[idx] * wrk[k] * factor_imag;
            }
    }
}
}

class RtopCalculator {
private:
    cudaStream_t main_stream_;
    cudaStream_t side_stream_;
    cublasHandle_t cublas_handle_;

    int64_t N_rs_;
    int64_t l_max_;
    int64_t N_thetas_;
    int64_t N_phis_;
    int64_t N_ps_;

    thrust::device_vector<double> d_BJ_;
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_wrk_;
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double>> d_wrk2mat_;
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double>> d_Psi_outer_spec_;
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double>> d_Psi_outer_spec_plm_;

    void allocate_internal() {
        d_BJ_.resize(N_rs_ * N_ps_ * N_thetas_);
        d_wrk_.resize(N_rs_);
        d_wrk2mat_.resize(N_thetas_ * N_rs_ * N_ps_);
        d_Psi_outer_spec_.resize(N_rs_ * N_thetas_ * N_phis_);
        d_Psi_outer_spec_plm_.resize(N_ps_ * N_thetas_ * N_phis_);
    }

public:
    RtopCalculator() {
        cudaStreamCreate(&main_stream_);
        cudaStreamCreate(&side_stream_);
        cublasCreate(&cublas_handle_);
        cublasSetStream(cublas_handle_, main_stream_);
    }

    ~RtopCalculator() {
        cudaStreamDestroy(main_stream_);
        cudaStreamDestroy(side_stream_);
        cublasDestroy(cublas_handle_);
    }

    void allocate(int64_t N_rs, int64_t l_max, int64_t N_ps) {
        N_rs_ = N_rs;
        l_max_ = l_max;
        N_thetas_ = l_max + 1;
        N_phis_ = 2 * l_max + 2;
        N_ps_ = N_ps;
        allocate_internal();
    }

    void compute(
        int64_t N_rs, int64_t l_max, int64_t N_ps,
        const double* __restrict__ BJ,
        const double* __restrict__ wrk,
        const double* __restrict__ Psi_outer_spec, // std::complex<double>
        double* __restrict__ Psi_outer_spec_plm,
        double* __restrict__ ris_without_ends = nullptr,
        double* __restrict__ r_primes_without_ends = nullptr,
        double* __restrict__ weights_Lobatto_without_ends = nullptr
    )
    {
        allocate(N_rs, l_max, N_ps);        

        int64_t N_phis = N_phis_;
        int64_t N_thetas = N_thetas_;

        double* d_BJ = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_BJ_.data());
        double* d_wrk = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_wrk_.data());
        thrust::complex<double>* d_wrk2mat = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_wrk2mat_.data());
        thrust::complex<double>* d_Psi_outer_spec = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Psi_outer_spec_.data());
        thrust::complex<double>* d_Psi_outer_spec_plm = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Psi_outer_spec_plm_.data());
        
        // the ordering of the next 4 statements are intended to interleave data transfer and compute
        // Cost 1
        cudaMemcpyAsync(d_BJ, BJ, N_rs * N_ps * (l_max + 1) * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, main_stream_);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(d_wrk, wrk, N_rs * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, main_stream_);                
        compute_wrk2mat<<<512, 256, 0, main_stream_>>>(
            N_ps, N_rs, l_max, d_BJ, d_wrk, reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(d_wrk2mat)
        );
        cudaMemcpyAsync(
            d_Psi_outer_spec, Psi_outer_spec,
            N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis * sizeof(std::complex<double>),
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, side_stream_
        );
        CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(main_stream_));
        CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(side_stream_));
        
        // Cost 2
        int64_t M = N_phis;
        int64_t K = N_rs;
        int64_t N = N_ps;
        int64_t lda = N_phis * N_thetas;
        int64_t ldb = N_rs;
        int64_t ldc = (l_max + 1) * N_phis;
        cuDoubleComplex* d_A = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(d_Psi_outer_spec);
        cuDoubleComplex* d_B = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(d_wrk2mat);
        cuDoubleComplex* d_C = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(d_Psi_outer_spec_plm);
        int64_t strideA = N_phis;
        int64_t strideB = N_rs * N_ps;
        int64_t strideC = N_phis;

        std::complex<double> alpha(1.0, 0.0);
        std::complex<double> beta(0.0, 0.0);

        CUBLAS_CHECK(cublasZgemmStridedBatched(
            cublas_handle_,
            CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N,
            M, N, K,
            (cuDoubleComplex*)&alpha,
            d_A, lda, strideA,
            d_B, ldb, strideB,
            (cuDoubleComplex*)&beta,
            d_C, ldc, strideC,
            l_max + 1
        ));

        // Cost 3
        cudaMemcpyAsync(
            Psi_outer_spec_plm, reinterpret_cast<double*>(d_Psi_outer_spec_plm),
            N_ps * N_thetas * N_phis * sizeof(std::complex<double>),
            cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, main_stream_
        );
        CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(main_stream_));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bool full_test = 0;
    if (argc > 1) full_test = 1;
    std::cout << "Full test = " << full_test << "\n";

    const int64_t N_rs = 1500;
    const int64_t l_max = 70;
    const int64_t N_thetas = l_max + 1;
    const int64_t N_phis = 2 * l_max + 2;
    const int64_t N_ps = 600;
    MyTimer timer;
    double total_cost[3] = {0};

    double* wrk = new double [N_rs];
    std::complex<double>* wrk2 = new std::complex<double> [N_rs * N_ps];
    double* BJ = new double [N_ps * N_rs * (l_max+1)];

    std::complex<double>* Psi_outer_spec = new std::complex<double> [N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis];
    std::complex<double>* Psi_outer_spec_plm_0 = new std::complex<double> [N_ps * N_thetas * N_phis];
    std::complex<double>* Psi_outer_spec_plm_1 = new std::complex<double> [N_ps * N_thetas * N_phis];
    std::complex<double>* Psi_outer_spec_plm_2 = new std::complex<double> [N_ps * N_thetas * N_phis];

    RtopCalculator calculator;
    calculator.allocate(N_rs, l_max, N_ps);
        
    int ntest = 5;
    int wrong = 0;
    for (int t = 1; t <= ntest; t++) {
        std::cout << "Start test " << t << "\n";
        GenData(N_rs, l_max, N_ps, Psi_outer_spec, BJ, wrk);

        if (full_test) {
            timer.startCounter();        
            rtop(N_rs, l_max, N_ps, Psi_outer_spec, Psi_outer_spec_plm_0, BJ, wrk, wrk2);
            total_cost[0] += timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
        }

        timer.startCounter();
        rtop_eigen(N_rs, l_max, N_ps, Psi_outer_spec, Psi_outer_spec_plm_1, BJ, wrk, wrk2);
        total_cost[1] += timer.getCounterMsPrecise();

        timer.startCounter();
        calculator.compute(
            N_rs, l_max, N_ps,
            BJ,
            wrk,
            reinterpret_cast<double*>(Psi_outer_spec),
            reinterpret_cast<double*>(Psi_outer_spec_plm_2)
        );
        total_cost[2] += timer.getCounterMsPrecise();

        std::cout << "cost = " << total_cost[0] << " " << total_cost[1] << " " << total_cost[2] << "\n";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ps; i++) 
        for (int l = 0; l < N_thetas; l++)
        for (int m = 0; m < N_phis; m++) {
            int64_t idx = i * (N_thetas * N_phis) + l * N_phis + m;
            auto res0 = Psi_outer_spec_plm_0[idx];
            auto res1 = Psi_outer_spec_plm_1[idx];
            auto res2 = Psi_outer_spec_plm_2[idx];

            if (full_test) {
                if (rcmp(res0.real(), res1.real()) || rcmp(res0.imag(), res1.imag()) ||
                    rcmp(res0.real(), res2.real()) || rcmp(res0.imag(), res2.imag())
                ) {
                    std::cout << "Error at (i=" << i << ",l=" << l << ",m=" << m << "): " << res0 << "; " << res1 << " " << res2 << "\n";
                    wrong++;
                    if (wrong == 20) exit(1);
                }
            } else {
                if (rcmp(res1.real(), res2.real()) || rcmp(res1.imag(), res2.imag())) {
                    std::cout << "Error at (i=" << i << ",l=" << l << ",m=" << m << "): " << res1 << "; " << res2 << "\n";                
                    wrong++;
                    if (wrong == 20) exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To run and test, use `run.sh`.

```
threads=$1  # The custom variable (number of threads) passed as the first argument
if [ -z "$threads" ]; then
  threads=8
fi
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$threads
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=$threads

nvcc -o main quantum.cu -O3 -std=c++17 -lcudart -lcublas -Xcompiler -march=native -Xcompiler -fopenmp -arch=native

echo "Running with $1 threads"
time ./main $2
```

For example:

```
./run.sh 1 # test Eigen 1 thread vs GPU
./run.sh 16 # test Eigen 16 thread vs GPU
./run.sh 16 1 # test all 3 versions. Remember the original code is very slow.
```

It's possible to turn this into a shared library which can be imported into Python and use with Tensorflow/Torch. But it's out of the scope of the question, so you can send me an email.

Comment: wonderful work. I will study and I hope someone else benefits from this, too.  I realized that from the point of view of Physics (what I research), that ``rtop`` function is not what I currently / at the moment need to accomplish my next task, so my lack of response for the moment. But in a few weeks time, I will need to use this function. So your work is very useful for me, at least.

Comment: I will run this on the A100 from the HPC cluster I have access and I will report the timings

Comment: As said, I don't currently need this function anymore, so I actually didn't test the same output is produced. Are you sure that the other answer's workflow produces negative of what shall be output? Thanks

Comment: You can run the program and replace the code in my `rtop_eigen` with the code in the other answer. Then run `./run.sh 16 1`. You'll see that `rtop` and `calculator.compute` gives the same result, and `rtop_eigen` gives a different result. Also it's not negative; the result complex number has correct magnitude, but wrong phase (so `(X,Y)` becomes either `(-X,-Y)`, `(-X, Y)` or `(X, -Y)`)

Comment: ahhh , ok , this is why I didn't see this. When I plot the data after the simulation, I mod square the wavefunction, i.e. the results of ``rtop``, so the phase information disappears, and I saw nothing wrong. Very interesting indeed.

Comment: Ok, I actually forgot what I did, I didn't copy the original answer with its phase part because I didn't understand that part of the code and I wrote that part myself, and it seems I wrote it correctly.

Comment: do you care about reputation on this forum and such other stuff? Shall I make your answer the accepted answer?